# Shiny Module Communication

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I am trying to create a dynamic UI based on user inputs. First, I am using an `lapply` inside Mod2.R to return the values of Mod1 onto Mod2 and save it in a `reactiveVal` object, which lives inside mod2.R and is saved as `binner_step_data`. The main app then also does an `lapply` on the return value of Mod2.R (which depends on Mod1.R) and saves it in a `reactiveVal` object, which is saved as `binner_data`.

### Mod1.R

```
   mod1_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        selectInput(ns("sel_step_name"), "Step Name", choices = c("step1", "step2"))
      )  # Column
      ,
      column(
        width = 3,
        numericInput(ns("num_threshold"), "Threshold", value = 0)
      )  # Column
    ) # Row
  ) # tag list
}

mod1_Server <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(
    list(
      step_name = reactive({input$sel_step_name}),
      threshold = reactive({input$num_threshold})
    )
  )
}
```

### Mod2.R

```
mod2_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        selectInput(ns("sel_n_steps"), "Number of Steps", selected = NULL, choices = 1:3),
        uiOutput(ns("ui_mod1_steps"))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        textInput(ns("txt_bin_name"), "Bin Name", placeholder = "Name of Bin e.g., Blocker", value = "**")
      )  # Column
    )  # Fluid Row
  ) # tag list  
}

mod2_Server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  binner_step_data <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$sel_n_steps{
    req(input$sel_n_steps)
    
    lapply(
      1:input$sel_n_steps,
      function(i) {
        res <- callModule(mod1_Server, paste0("binner_step", i), binner_number = reactive(i), dat = reactive(dat()))
        return(res)
      }
    ) %>% binner_step_data(.)
  })
  
  output$ui_mod1_steps <- renderUI({
    
    req(input$sel_n_steps)
    
    tagList(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 12,
          lapply(
            1:as.numeric(input$sel_n_steps),
            function(i) {
              mod1_UI(ns(paste0("binner_step_", i)))
            }
          )  # lapply
        )  # Column
      )  # Fluid Row
    )  # Tag List
    
  })
  
  return(
    list(
      bin_name = reactive({input$txt_bin_name}),
      bin_criteria = reactive({lapply(binner_step_data(), function(step_data) { step_data() })})
    )
  )
  
}
```

Here are my first two modules, in which Mod2.R is using the return values of Mod1.R. Now here's the main app.R file that is using the return value of Mod2.R.

### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Modules
source("Mod1.R")
source("Mod2.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      numericInput("num_bins", "Number of Bins", value = NULL, min = 1, max = 10)
    )  # Column
  )  # Fluid Row
  ,
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      uiOutput("ui_binners")
    )  # Column
  ),  # FLuid Row
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      verbatimTextOutput("reactive_output_from_mod2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  binner_data <- reactiveVal()
  
  # Modules -----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  observeEvent(input$num_bins, {
    req(input$num_bins)
    
    lapply(
      1:input$num_bins,
      function(i) {
        res <- callModule(mod2_Server, paste0("binner_", i))
        return(res)
      }
    ) %>% binner_data(.)
  })
  
  output$ui_binners <- renderUI({
    
    req(input$num_bins)
    
    tagList(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 12,
          lapply(
            1:input$num_bins,
            function(i) {
              mod2_UI(paste0("binner_", i))
            }
          )  # lapply
        )  # Column
      )  # Fluid Row
    )  # Tag List
    
  })
  
  output$reactive_output_from_mod2 <- renderPrint({
    # req(input$sel_n_steps)
    binner_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

At the end, I'm using a renderPrint to confirm that the values I need are getting passed to the main server but apparently they are not. I should get back a list of two, with the first element being the Bin name and the second element being the Bin Criteria (Step Name + Threshold Value). What is the best way to handle the return values from the two modules to get back the data that I need? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that BinnerMod.R is returning something valid that can be passed to BinnerStep.R? It's really hard to test answers without a working app, and there are many possible issues with modularized apps. I recognize the challenge, but any chance you could make a reduced version that recreates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To move values out of the server modules, you want the individual elements to be reactive, not the entire list. This structure at the end of BinnerStep.R should provide a list of reactive elements returned from the server module.

```
return(list(
  step_name = reactive({input$sel_step_name}),
  threshold = reactive({input$num_threshold}),
  rank_direction = reactive({input$sel_rank_direction})
))
```

Comment: what if I need to return a reactive expression, like tib_data(), do I return it like that or reactive({tib_data()})?

Comment: If you construct `tib_data` as a `reactiveValues` object, you use the same form as above - i.e., `reactive({tib_data})`. Within a reactive context like an observer or a render call, you can use `tib_data()` to access the values. See the [shiny tutorials on reactivity](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) for more details.

Comment: I have something that gets created as eventReactive() named as tib_data, and I'm trying to return that value to its caller Module and can't get that. When I try `return(reactive({tib_data}))`  all I literally get back is "return(reactive({tib_data})". I know this because I'm printing as part of verbatimTextOutput

Comment: Without a working app, it's nearly impossible to know what could be going wrong. Any progress on making a minimal version of the app?